# Why does A - 4I give me the following matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let matrix A be =

\begin{bmatrix}3&1\\1&3\end{bmatrix}

Now if I want to do A-4I, shouldn't I get the following?

\begin{bmatrix}-1&-3\\-3&-1\end{bmatrix}

but at the 27:04 mark in this video from MIT (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cdZnhQjJu4I), we get:

\begin{bmatrix}-1&1\\1&-1\end{bmatrix}

Could someone please explain why only the diagonals are getting affected?

Comment: This is because $I$ denotes the $2 \times 2$ identity matrix, which is defined by $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: It would probably be educational for you to try to multiply a vector by what you thought the identity matrix was, and what it actually is, to see the difference.

Comment: $\begin{bmatrix}3&1\\1&3\end{bmatrix} - 4\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}3&1\\1&3\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}-4&0\\0&-4\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}3-4&1\\1&3-4\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}-1&1\\1&-1\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: okay, I understood. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I is the identity matrix, consisting ones on the diagonal (rest is equal to zero). This matrix is chosen such that for any matrix A, AI = IA = A. So 4I is the diagonal matrix with only fours on the diagonal.